# document.selection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need to know what is the use of following code:

```
var obj=document.selection.createRange();
obj.moveStart('character', count);
```

From what I understand, obj will have the selected text.

What is `moveStart` is used for..?

Comment: As you've probably realised, this code is IE specific and will not work in other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536623%28VS.85%29.aspx), that call moves the start of the selection by count characters to the right.

Obj will not be a string by the way, it'll be a TextRange object instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28VS.85%29.aspx#